# Should the tag "advertisement" be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [advertisement](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertisement) has no usage guidance and has no meaningful question tagged under it. Should we remove this tag?

Comment: Perhaps, but the problem is it's currently tagged on 2 questions: [1](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/24236/7792) and [2](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/23475/7792). Q1 will be automatically deleted by the system, but Q2 won't because it has an accepted/upvoted answer. On the other hand, a question always *needs* to have at least 1 tag. So there are 2 options to burninate this tag: replace the tag on Q2 to something else or delete Q2.

Comment: @AndrewT. for Q2 the tag seems rather irrelevant IMO. Surely we could find something better while allowing this tag to be removed?

Comment: @Brandon_J well, it could be [tag:meme], but... do we want that instead? I prefer to delete the question since I don't see any value on it...

Comment: @AndrewT. I agree

Comment: I agree with both of you, I think that the tag and both questions could be deleted.

Answer (score 5):

Both questions have been deleted by a ♦ moderator and the tag is gone now. So this request is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).